# Why state inside mapStateToProps functions is always "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am making a very basic counter app using react native and i am using redux in it for practice, but i am getting some problem.

## Problem

In the mapStateToProps() function in my HomeScreen Component, the state argument, passed, is always getting a value of *undefined*, therefore my UI is also not updating. I used Redux DevTools and monitored the state and i get to know the state is changing absolutely fine on clicking the two buttons but inside mapStateToProps() function, it is always *undefined*.

Please correct me where I am going wrong.

This is my `HomeComponent` code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as counterActions from '../redux/actions/counterAction';

class HomeScreen extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.homeView}>
                <View>
                <Text style={styles.homeText}>Basic Counter</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.counterStyle}>
                    <View style={{marginRight: 20, width: 50}}>
                    <Button title="-" onPress={() => this.props.decreaseCounter()}></Button>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 40, color: 'black'}}> {"Value = " + this.props.count} </Text>
                    <View style={{marginLeft: 20, width: 50}}>
                    <Button title="+" onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter()} ></Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    homeView: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 24,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    homeText: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 24,
    },
    counterStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state.count
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch(counterActions.increaseCounter()),
        decreaseCounter: () => dispatch(counterActions.decreaseCounter())
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

This is my reducer function

```
const initialState = {
    count: 0
};

export default function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case "INCREASE_COUNTER":
            return {
                ...state,
                count: state.count + 1
            };
        case "DECREASE_COUNTER":
            return {
                ...state,
                count: state.count - 1
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is my root level component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/index';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const store  = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Main />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add a console.log(state) inside `function mapStateToProps()`. What do you see? I think you need to go with `state.counterReducer.count`

Comment: i tried console.log(state) inside function mapStateToProps(), it is showing "undefined".

Comment: @EmadEmami thank you very much, by using state.counterReducer.count , it is working fine.

Comment: But i am not able to understand the reason, please let me know...

Comment: I replied you as an answer down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must retrieve the `count` from the specific 'reducer' that you have `state.counterReducer.count`. In this case, your reducer is `counterReducer`.

Redux always assumes you have multiple reducers because each reducer is by itself and changing each reducer shouldn't update another reducer. Redux uses `combineReducers` for separating them.

you can read [redux documentation about combining reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#combined-reducers)

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this, you'll also need to show your `rootReducer` as well as the `counterActions` file. I'd likely guess there's an issue in one of those files if state isn't properly showing up in `mapStateToProps`. I've taken your example and moved it into a code sandbox where state and props are accurately reflected. Here are the changes I made. Keep in mind this is in the context of a web application, and not a react-native app, but since this is only dealing with state it shouldn't matter much.

App.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import Home from "./Home";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Home />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import counterActions from "./reducers/counter/counterActions";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Basic Counter</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.props.decreaseCounter}>-</button>
          </div>
          <p style={{ fontSize: 40, color: "black" }}>
            {`value= ${this.props.count}`}
          </p>
          <div style={{ marginLeft: 20, width: 50 }}>
            <button onClick={this.props.increaseCounter}>+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state.counter.count
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    increaseCounter: () => dispatch(counterActions.increaseCounter()),
    decreaseCounter: () => dispatch(counterActions.decreaseCounter())
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen);
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import counterReducer from "./counter/counterReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducers/counter/counterReducer.js

```
import { actionConstants } from "./counterActions";

const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

export default function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionConstants.INCREASE_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1
      };
    case actionConstants.DECREASE_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

reducers/counter/counterActions.js

```
const actionConstants = {
  INCREASE_COUNTER: "INCREASE_COUNTER",
  DECREASE_COUNTER: "DECREASE_COUNTER"
};

const counterActions = {
  increaseCounter() {
    return {
      type: actionConstants.INCREASE_COUNTER
    };
  },

  decreaseCounter() {
    return {
      type: actionConstants.DECREASE_COUNTER
    };
  }
};

export { counterActions as default, actionConstants };
```

[Heres's a link to the working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-redux-counter-qw81w)

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable efforts, it really helped me . Thank you.